# Orientation of viewController

Tags: iphone

i am having tabBarController.It is having 3 viewControllers.I want to support landscape mode in only one of these viewControlers.and other 2 view controllers in potrait mode.How to achive this.

Answer (score 1):

In the view controller you want to support landscape simply return YES to

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation

Of course I'm assuming your implementation is creating a view controller for each view

Comment: This is assuming you have things wired correctly, for example if you have one root view controller and you are simply adding the view controller subviews to the root controllers view your "other" view controllers views wont rotate automatically at all

Answer (score 0):

Ya i am having view for each viewController.But i want to support landscape in only one view and rest all in potrait mode.Even i am returning YES in (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
if interfaceOrientation is landsape in view which i want to support and in rext views  i am returning NO in this method if interfaceOrientation is landScape mode.